# Could GUID contains static information about source where was generated

Tags: c#, .net

I generate version 4 GUID value, which contains y is on of  8,9,A,B. Could be given y value used as source parameter and wouldn't be generated randomly?

Wikipedia definition:
Version 4 UUIDs have the form `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` where x is any hexadecimal digit and y is one of 8, 9, A, or B (e.g., `f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479`).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why would you want to fix a certain value in a Guid?

Comment: Question is : Can I change y value after generating a GUID value in .NET without risk? For example - A - web source, B - web service source...

Comment: @Tomas Sure you can change it anyway you like. But to maintain uniqueness you shouldn't do that.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx)

Comment: OK, I need provide uniqueness in my solution, what about to change the version of GUID to A - web source, B - web service source Example : 7ac10b-58cc-a372-a567-0e02b2c3d479 is given GUID valid?

Comment: Its just a number so its valid. But still uniqueness is at risk.

Comment: Can't you use another property in order to identify them?

Comment: Luis, what do you mean by another property? I only have GUID value, another option is... add one more char to string representation of GUID and save it as a string.

Comment: Why the uniqueness is at risk for version value of GUID, if Windows always generate 4?

Comment: I think you've gone about this problem exactly backwards. There's some problem that you're trying to solve that you *think* a GUID (perhaps with a few modifications) will help you solve. Any now your fiddling around trying to make more modifications to this solution - but you haven't really been clear with us what the actual problem that you're trying to solve is.

Comment: I have users, who send only GUID parameter during the communication as user id. Based on the place where was GUID generated, I need add char value. I was thinking about using version part of GUID as a wearer of given information. I can add this information as next char into GUID value, but it will change the concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what system generated the Guid. Windows for example uses some format where one of the places is always `4`. I think the scheme is well-documented. (I'm not a fan of it - a purely random Guid would have been just as unique and less vulnerable to attacks).

If you want that information to not be exposed, generate 16 random bytes and there's your Guid. You can even generate them cryptographically secure.